# spring mvc integration with hdfc payment gateway

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, payment-gateway

Hii I want to build an ecommerce website where I can integrate various payment gateways like hdfc,icici,sbi,kotak,etc.How can it be implemented in spring mvc projects.What are the interfaces,jars,classes required.Do we need to register anywhere.Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer help you

Answer (score 1):

There are various payment gateway available for indian merchant like:

1. [CCAvenue](http://www.ccavenue.com/)
2. [ebs](https://www.ebs.in/)
3. [Citrus Pay](http://www.citruspay.com/)
4. [DirecPay](http://www.direcpay.com/direcpay/home.jsp)
5. [PayUmoney](https://www.payumoney.com/)

I would suggest you to use `CCAvenue`. To integrate CCavenue Payment gateway  to your website. you will need to follow below step:

1. create account in CCAvenue.
2. verify your mobile and email.
3. your account will activate within a hour.
4. you will get username and password
5. CCAvenue's technical team will check you website ans content and based on that they will mail you.
6. there are some document you need to provide them like cancelled cheque, undertaking form etc.
7. after that they will give you marchant id based on your website